# Getiing this error-__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: python, django

im using a non-model based form django.
once i get the data,i create a model object.
but when im trying to edit my post(a blog/quote based app),im not able to create a form object using the model object for a specific post.

these are my codes:

views.py:

```
def quote_form(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form=Quote(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        quote=form.cleaned_data['quote']
        author=form.cleaned_data['author']
        popularity=form.cleaned_data['popularity']
        category=form.cleaned_data['category']
        p=Quote1(quote=quote, author=author, popularity=popularity, category=category)
        p.save()
        return redirect("quote_list")
else:
    form=Quote()
    return render(request,'quote/form.html',{'form':form})


def quote_edit(request, pk):
    q = get_object_or_404(Quote1, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Quote(request.POST,instance=q)
        if form.is_valid():
            q = form.save(commit=False)
            q.author = request.user
            q.save()
            return redirect('quote_detail', pk=q.pk)
            #return render(request,"blog/post_detail.html",{'post':post})
    else:
        form = Quote(instance=q)
        return render(request, 'quote/quote_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py:

```
class Quote1(models.Model):
    quote=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    popularity=models.IntegerField()
    category=models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

forms.py:

```
class Quote(forms.Form):
    quote=forms.CharField()
    author=forms.CharField()
    popularity=forms.IntegerField()
    category=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('life','life'),('happiness','happiness'),('love','love'),('truth','truth'),
                                    ('inspiration','inspiration'),('humor','humor'),('philosophy','philosophy'),('science','science')])
```

Comment: Your `Quote` is *not* a `ModelForm`, hence it indeed can *not* process the `instance` parameter since, well, it is not editing a model object.

Comment: so how do i solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def quote_edit(request, pk): 
    q = get_object_or_404(Quote1, pk=pk) 
    if request.method == "POST": 
    form = Quote(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():  
        quote=form.cleaned_data['quote'] 
        author=form.cleaned_data['author']
        popularity=form.cleaned_data['popularity']
        category=form.cleaned_data['category'] 
        q.quote=quote
        q.author=author
        q.popularity=popularity
        q.category=category
        q.save()
    else: 
        form = Quote(initial=reauest.POST.copy())
        return render(request, 'quote/quote_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

P.S:
Using ModelForm would have been better approach. If you can switch to ModelForm i can help there as well.

Comment: its creating a new quote instead.